# PHP - Anonymous Function

Tags: php, function, syntax

Why doesn't this work:

```
echo (function() {
    if (strlen($_POST["a"]) > 150) {
        return "123";
    }

    return "abc";
})();
```

is there anyway to do this in PHP?

Like in JS you can do:

```
var x = (function() {return "asd";})();
```

Comment: Maybe your looking for something like this: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Why would you be able to do it in php just because you can do it in js? They're different languages

Comment: @Clive It's not an unreasonable question to ask if similar functionality exists...

Comment: evet it would be js, you still have parentheses mistake on "echo"

Comment: @lonesomeday I was addressing the first part of the question, "Why doesn't this work".

Comment: @Adem Just to make it look better, not because idk that "echo" is not a function

Comment: I meant, it should be echo(function(){...}()); btw, @lonesomeday's answer is pretty good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, just not with the elegant syntax of Javascript. You need [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php):

```
echo call_user_func(function() {
    if (strlen($_POST["a"]) > 150) {
        return "123";
    }

    return "abc";
});
```